# Write contained expression in LLBL Genpro

Tags: c#, lambda, llblgenpro

How can i write some code with LLBL GenPro like that:

```
var myString = "Blah,Blah,Blah,Blah";
DbContext.MyTableName.Where(a => myString.Contains(a.TableFiledName.ToString()))
```

It's lambda expression with entity but now i want to do the same thing in LLBL Genpro, how can i do it?

Please help
thanks

Comment: Have you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are referring to [LLBLGen Framework](http://llblgen.com/Documentation/5.4/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/index.htm) (LLBLGen Designer [supports generating code for multiple O/RM Framerowks](http://llblgen.com/Documentation/5.4/Designer/supportedorms.htm)), this is how it would look like [using QuerySpec](http://llblgen.com/Documentation/5.4/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/Using%20the%20generated%20code/QuerySpec/gencode_queryspec_generalusage.htm#filtering-the-resultset-where):

```
var myString = "Blah,Blah,Blah,Blah";

var qf = new QueryFactory();
var q = qf.Customer.Where(CustomerFields.Country.Contains(myString));
```

Or very similar, using [Linq2LLBL](http://llblgen.com/Documentation/5.4/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/Using%20the%20generated%20code/Linq/gencode_linq_generalusage.htm):

```
var myString = "Blah,Blah,Blah,Blah";

var metaData = new LinqMetaData(adapter);
var q = from c in metaData.Customer where c.Country.Contains(myString);
```